# Firebase CM Unregistered registration token

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm using `react-native-firebase` v4.0.3 to send push notifications on devices.

After using:

```
firebase.messaging().getToken().then((notifyToken) => {
    console.log(notifyToken)
})
```

And using the logged token in the firebase console (Cloud messaging section), everything works fine with iOS but with Android, I keep having a fail with `Unregistered registration token`

I already have checked multiple times the installation instructions and I can't find the source of my problem, the file `google-service.json` is downloaded from firebase console directly.

Is there something special to do while the installation of the plugin?

I will provide `.gradle` files and `android manifest` if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after 2 days on horrible investigation, I found the problem.

At the start, my app was built with expo, but I had to detach for bluetooth usage.
In the last expokit update, I had to replace some files in the android folder.

So, in the android manifest, the package was = to `host.exp.exponent` instead of my `package name`.

Since my package name was declared in firebase and not `host.exp.exponent` the token was not registered to my package name.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue with iOS and the solution was to ensure the following:

1. The bundle ID for my application under App IDs on my Apple Developer account dashboard matched the bundle ID found in Xcode under General > Identity
2. The bundle ID in step 1 matched what I had set for my bundle ID when I created my iOS application in Firebase console.